# knit to PDF not working R V4.0.0 RStudio V1.2.5042

Tags: r

Unable to get RStudio to knit to PDF post-RV4.0.0 update HTML, WORD work).
Error returned: Searching for luatex.dll, which does not seem to install following (i)  install.packages('tinytex') (ii) tinytex::install_tinytex().
Curiously, luatex.dll is found in my older 3.5.3 and 3.6.3 .\TinyTeX\bin\win32 directories.  rTools is current for R4.0.0, with path added per website.  Similarly, pdflatex.fmt mising in install from 4.0.0.  In all cases followed advice from Yihui Xie et al. websites.
Have tried several re-installs, including a full install of MikTeX.  No joy.
tinytex Version is 0.22.  basic session info is:

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

I am puzzled because I have successfully installed tinytext etc on 3.X.X R and previous versions of RStudio, and knited PDFs (including use of bookkdown) with no problems.  Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you exit RStudio and reopen and confirm  that `tinytex:::is_tinytex()` is TRUE.

Comment: Yes. > tinytex:::is_tinytex()  # check if installation worked
[1] TRUE